# Batch copy time creation date from files using OSX

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I'm having a hard time trying to copy the creation date of some files to other files.

I have converted some MXF files to MOV, but unfortunately the new MOV-files don't have the same creation date.

 Info: The files are definitely *MXF and *mov.

Now I had a look around for similar questions and found different answers:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for f in *.MXF; do
     touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"
    done
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to edit the creation date, but only the modification date. Is there some way to copy the creation date, also?

**Edit:**
I have also found this code, which seems to be working – but still no creation date.

```
set folder1 to POSIX file "/POSIX/path/to/MFX/folder"
set folder2 to POSIX file "/POSIX/path/to/MOV/folder"
 
tell application "Finder"
    set folder1 to folder folder1
    set folder2 to folder folder2
    set N to (count folder1)
    if not (count folder2) = N then return
    set creationDates to creation date of files of folder1
    set modificationDates to modification date of files of folder1
    repeat with k from 1 to N
        my changeDates(file k of folder2, item k of creationDates, item k of modificationDates)
    end repeat
end tell
 
on changeDates(theFile, theCreationDate, theModificationDate)
    tell application "Finder"
        set modification date of theFile to theCreationDate
        set modification date of theFile to theModificationDate
    end tell
end changeDates
```

But I want it change the creation and modification date. Unfortunately I am getting an error when I change
 `set modification date of theFile to theCreationDate` 
to 
`set creation date of theFile to theCreationDate`

How can I copy the creation date, too?

Comment: `*.MXF` in first 2 examples will use `.MXF` files from current directory. Use absolute path `/path/*.MXF` or put your script in directory which contains `*.MXF` and `*.mov` files.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `.MXF`, not `.mxf`? Even though OS X filesystems are usually case-insensitive, bash's wildcard matching is case-sensitive.

Comment: You can use `shopt -s nocaseglob` to make wildcards case-insensitive.

Comment: But the variable substitution `${orig/.MXF/.mov}` is case-sensitive. You need to do `${orig/.[Mm][Xx][Ff]/.mov}`

Comment: @Barmar, unfortunately I have tried this before and was still getting the above stated error.
Might there be something else wrong, maybe some rights problems or some wrong choice in Automator?

Comment: You need some clarity on how the files are really named. Try starting Terminal, and using `cd` to go to the directory where the MXF files are, like this `cd "path/to/MXFfiles"`. Then run `ls *MXF` to see all files ending in `MXF` and run `ls *mxf` to see all files sending in `mxf`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for the info. The files are definitely MXF.
Might there be a problem that the Hard drive is formatted in exFat?

Comment: There's a script [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4467041?start=0&tstart=0) that will copy modification dates to creation dates.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much for the script, but unfortunately it doesn't copy creation date from file1.MXF to file1.mov... Since the modification and creation dates are different for most of my files (created: start of shooting; modified: end of shooting), I'd need a script to copy both values from file1.mxf to file1.mov

Comment: The script shows the mechanism to set the creation date. Modify it to get the date from the other file's creation date instead of the same file's modification date.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, I'll have a look into that. :) Hopefully I'll get it done.